# Measure load or performance testing of GUI web applications

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

We are using JMeter to perform load testing of apis. If want to perform load or stress testing on web application which has JavaScript rendering, would JMeter with Selenium only option or any other options can be utilized like Selenium functional tests integrate with any performance tool.

Please suggest.

Have gone through/referred to this questions:
[How to approach "end-client" performance testing on single-page (web) applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21780391/how-to-approach-end-client-performance-testing-on-single-page-web-applicatio)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can choose to use Selenium but it's hard to generate high load using selenium based test. You can choose to run two performance tests in parallel

1. **Back-end Performance test:** Use this to inject load on the back-end. Record Network traffic for the journey steps using [JMeter proxy](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#configure-browser). Take out third-party and static urls, which are not relevant to load test.
2. **Front-end performance test:** Use this to measure end-user impact. Use between 1 - 5 virtual users in this test. Generating load is not important in this case, so you can use low amount of virtual users in this case. You can either use selenium based load test, webpagetest.org or similar tools.

This approach is more efficient than the selenium based performance test because selenium based load test will require very high amount of compute resources to scale.

If you use [taurus](https://gettaurus.org/docs/ExecutionSettings/) to run your perf test then it should make it easier to run two JMeter tests in parallel using bzt scenario1.jmx scenario2.jmx

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the valuable guidance, with Taurus I guess can execute backend performance tests only not selenium tests,please correct me if I am wrong. Also, if front end already taking time to load the page ex, 8 secs then will it make sense to do front end load testing?

Comment: yes, if you use webdriver sampler you can run selenium test. However if you think your front end is already slow, probably because of JS rendering then, use webpagetest.org to see waterfall chart and see what's slowing your front-end down. If you choose to record video then it should give you a nice progressive screenshots to see your page load time.

Comment: Thanks again, the main challenge with webpagetest.org is to test the performance of website after login, login authentication has to work in webpagetest.org.

Comment: If you write a script for webpagetest you can test a page behind login page. Have a look at https://www.webpagetest.org/forums/showthread.php?tid=14753. Make sure you tick keep my test private and script contains sensitive information so it's not visible to anyone. Alternatively you can use chrome developer tools to see which call/s is/are slowing your page down.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you're trying to achieve and how many machine power you have you can consider:

1. Running Selenium tests in parallel using [Selenium Grid](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/Grid2) but in this case:

   - you will need to ensure to have enough CPU, RAM, etc., i.e [Firefox 72](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/72.0.2/system-requirements/) needs 1 CPU and 2 GB of RAM per single browser instance
   - you will not have [HTTP protocol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP) specific metrics (Connect time, time to first byte, time to last byte, etc.) and load test specific metrics (active threads over time, transactions per second, etc)
2. Conducting the main load using JMeter HTTP Request samplers (just make sure to properly [configure JMeter to behave like a real browser](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733719-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser)) and have 1-2 threads running [WebDriver Sampler](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverSampler/) to collect client-side performance metrics i.e from [Performance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance) object